# How to run two docker containers from cron?

Tags: bash, docker, cron, startup

I am trying to set up `crontab` to run two `docker` containers on system startup/reboot. The line I use to do this after entering the command `crontab -e` is:

```
@reboot sh folder_b/run_docker_containers.bash
```

The script `run_docker_containers.bash` has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
# Run containers based on setup_image and main_image
sudo bash /home/user/folder_a/run_setup_docker_container.bash
sudo bash /home/user/folder_b/run_main_docker_container.bash
```

The scripts `run_setup_docker_container.bash` and `run_main_docker_container.bash` both have the following contents (where `docker_image` is `setup_image` and `main_image`, respectively):

```
#!/bin/bash

/snap/bin/docker run \
    --rm \
    --detach \
    --privileged \
    --net=host \
    --device /dev/bus/usb \
    docker_image:latest \
    /bin/bash -c\
    "
     *SOME COMMANDS*
    "
export containerId=$(/snap/bin/docker ps -l -q)
```

However, the containers are not run when the script is executed on reboot. I prove it finds the script `folder_b/run_docker_containers.bash` by adding the following code to it and seeing that the new file has been created after reboot.

```
touch proof_that_crontab_has_done_something.txt
```

It seems that `crontab` cannot find the scripts `run_setup_docker_container.bash` and `run_main_docker_container.bash`. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a shellscript with sudo rights I would recommend using the sudo crontab.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Your personal cronjob should not be able to start a shell with sudo rights. Unless you do some weird modifications.

Use the absolute path

```
 @reboot     /...../folder_b/run_docker_containers.bash
```